# Symplectic Structure without predefined Hamiltonian

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian-formalism

Here there is a [link](http://math.mit.edu/%7Ecohn/Thoughts/symplectic.html) which has helped me understanding the relationship between symplectic geometry and classical mechanincs. In short, the symplectic form transforms the derivative of the Hamiltonian, $dH$, into the evolution direction, $V$. But a symplectic form gives much more information than the field $V$ itself, so it is a natural question: **does the symplectic form mean something on its own?** Here there are two examples to explain the question (with two variables $x$ and $v$, in the first case referring to length and in the second to angle):

1. The dynamics of a mass linked to a dock.

$H=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+\frac{1}{2}kx^2$,

$\mathrm{d}H=kx\mathrm{d}x+mv\mathrm{d}v$,

$V=(v,-\frac{k}{m}x)$,

$\omega=\omega(x,v)\mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}v$,

$\omega(V,X=(a,b))=\omega(x,v)[vb+\frac{k}{m}xa]=kxa+mvb\Longrightarrow\omega=m\mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}v$

2. The dynamics of a pendulum.

$H=\frac{1}{2}m(vL)^2+mgL(1-\cos(x))$,

$\mathrm{d}H=mgL\sin(x)\mathrm{d}x+mL^2v\mathrm{d}v$,

$V=(v,-\frac{g\sin(x)}{L})$,

$\omega=\omega(x,v)\mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}v$,

$\omega(V,X=(a,b))=\omega(x,v)[vb+\frac{g\sin(x)}{L}a]=mgL\sin(x)a+mL^2vb\Longrightarrow\omega=mL^2\mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}v$

and in both cases the symplectic form is much simpler than the Hamiltonian itself. It looks as if the symplectic form was in some sense previous than the Hamiltonian, valid for multiple choices of the last. **Is there really a physcal explanation of this fact?** Any idea will be welcomed.

Comment: Note that "simpler" is not a well-defined concept, and that, by [Darboux' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem), you can always locally make the symplectic form look just like $\mathrm{d}x^i \wedge \mathrm{d}p_i$. Therefore, I'm not entirely sure what the "fact" is you're seeking a physical explanation for.#

Comment: Related MO.SE posts: http://mathoverflow.net/q/19932/13917 (this even links to the very same webpage), http://mathoverflow.net/q/19932/13917 , http://mathoverflow.net/q/157633/13917 , http://mathoverflow.net/q/189024/13917 (by OP), and links therein.

Comment: note that because you chose to consider the problem in velocity phase space instead of momentum phase space, the symplectic form depends on mass; in momentum phase space, the symplectic form is what you end up with if you forget about the geometry of the cotangent bundle and just keep the bare minimum you need to transform forms to vector fields, enabling the derivation of evolution equations from potentials; it's less about physics and more about geometry